# Работа со структурами данных в двоичном файле

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, подскажите где взять информацию по поводу работы с двоичными файлами. Но мне нужно не так как записать, к примеру, массив в файл, а как работать в самом файле, то есть создавать структуру данных(дерево, список и тд) сразу в файле и там с ней работать. 
Больше всего меня в заблуждение вводит способ добавления объекта в такую структуру. То есть в обычном, например, дереве мы имеем в классе поле объект, а тут то такого не будет, мы добавляем непосредственно сразу в файл.

Comment: Всякая структура данных описывается некоторыми полями. Если вы их запишете в файл и потом прочитаете - получите ту же самую структуру.

Comment: А что, по-вашему, есть двоичный файл?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы хотите, к примеру, связный список сразу в файле реализовать? Ну так просто в тех местах, где начинаете играться с указателями начинайте оперировать не ими, а позицией в файле. Т.е. нельзя вот так взять и одним write() записать в файл 'std::map' (ну, точнее, можно, только толку от этого вам не будет), а потом в другом месте восстановить его одним махом.

А можете использовать отображение в память (mmap или аналоги), натравить на этот блок свой аллокатор (а можно и не натравливать, ручками с адресами играть). Главное указатели пересчитывать относительно смещения, которое вернёт mmap.

А если вы напишете ещё что-то подробнее, то можно и ответ дополнить.

Comment: Да, сразу в файле. А вот насчет занесения объекта в структуру, как тут быть? Тупо написать функцию, у которой аргумент и будет этим самым объектом, и эта функция с помощью переходов по файловым указателям, смотрит куда впихнуть? Например, я хочу пользоваться seekp и seekg, то есть мне придется самому следить за занятыми/незанятыми местами?

Comment: Примерно. Но лучше посмотрите на механизм отображения файла в память. Тогда вы так же будете оперировать с указателями в терминах адресной арифметики. Ну и что значит внести объект в структуру? Хотите использовать std::vector и сделать push_back? Не получится. Все ваши структуры данных и логика работы с ними должна знать, что это работа в файле, правильно интерпретировать смещения и т.д.

Comment: Забыл сказать, что эту структуру данных я реализую сам, а не пользуюсь STL, поэтому  все зацикливаюсь на добавлении:) Мне просто сложно как-то переходить от работы с памятью к файлу, для меня привычно и понятно как это добавление делается с помощью обычных указателей, а вот файл меня вводит в какой-то ступор.

Comment: Грубо, связный список: http://pastebin.com/kMLiJKUs остальные операции придётся реализовывать схожим образом. Т.е. везде где может появиться адрес в памяти - вы должны контроллировать. Поэтому никаких виртуальных методов, никаких стандарт... Хотя со стандартными контейнерами можно похимичить через кастомные аллокаторы. По крайней мере мне так видится.

Comment: Добавление в файле будет просто: открыли файл на модификацию/добавление, дописали структуру в конец, сместились на sizeof(Foo) назад, сместились на sizeof(Foo::next) вперёд (понятно, что можно посчитать и сделать в одну операцию), записали вместо 0 новое значение. Аналогично с изменением порядка - просто жонглируете при помощи смещений. А вот удалять сложнее, особенно из середины: вам нужно сначала сдвинуть все последующие струтуры назад, а потом пробежаться и все смещения которые указывали за этот объект пересчитать. Винт шуршать будет сильно.

Comment: Ну и ещё раз: посмотрите в сторону mmap, вы так же будете работать с адресами, но: после мапинга нужно пробежаться и увеличить значения всех указателей на membase (адрес начала области мапинга), а перед анмапингам снова пробежаться, но уже вычесть membase из каждого указателя. Главное не убегите за область мапинга. И, если мне не изменяет память, нельзя область увеличивать. Т.е. для добавления нужно анмпапить, увеличивать файл, потом папить заново.