# Удаление структуры из файла

Tags: c++, c, файлы, структуры

Программа-телефонный справочник, по запросу можно добавить новый контакт, удалить контакт, найти контакт по номеру телефона, найти контакт по фамилии и адресу, вывести всю базу. Проблемы возникают только в функции, удаляющей контакт(udalit_kontakt) так как после удаления контакта все поля остальных контактов заполняются произвольными символами. Как можно исправить эту ошибку?
Прошу прощения за дикую смесь C и С++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<cstring>
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct contact
{
    char nomer[12];
    char adress[50];
    char sname[20];
};

int vivod_bazi()
{
    system("cls");
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("telbook.dat", "r+b");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(f);
    int kol_el = size / sizeof(contact);
    contact *buf = new contact[kol_el];
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buf, sizeof(contact), kol_el, f);
    cout << "Полный список контактов базы данных\n";
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < kol_el; i++)
    {
        cout << (i + 1) << ".) " << buf[i].sname;
        cout << "\n" << buf[i].nomer;
        cout << "\n" << buf[i].adress;
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    fclose(f);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }    

int poisk_po_nomeru()
{
    system("cls"); 
    char otvet = 'y';
    do{
        FILE *f;
        f = fopen("telbook.dat", "r+b");
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        int size = ftell(f);
        int kol_el = size / sizeof(contact);
        contact *buf = new contact[kol_el];
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fread(buf, sizeof(contact), kol_el, f);
        char poisk_nomer[12];
        cout << "Введите номер абонента:";
        fflush(stdin);
        cin >> poisk_nomer;
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; ((i < kol_el) && k != -1); i++)
        {
            if ((strcmp(poisk_nomer, buf[i].nomer)) == 0)
                {
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "Результаты запроса.\n";
                    cout << "Фамилия:" << buf[i].sname;
                    cout << "\nНомер телефона:" << buf[i].nomer;
                    cout << "\nАдрес:" << buf[i].adress;
                    k = -1;
                };
        }
        if (k == 0)
            cout << "\nКонтакт не найден.";
        cout << "\nПовторить запрос?[y/n]";
        fflush(stdin);
        otvet = getchar();
    } while (otvet != 'n');
    return 0;
}

int poisk_po_fam()
{
    system("cls");
    char otvet = 'y';
    do{
        FILE *f;
        f = fopen("telbook.dat", "r+b");
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        int size = ftell(f);
        int kol_el = size / sizeof(contact);
        contact *buf = new contact[kol_el];
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fread(buf, sizeof(contact), kol_el, f);
        char poisk_sname[20];
        char poisk_adress[50];
        cout << "Введите фамилию абонента:";
        fflush(stdin);
        cin >> poisk_sname;    
        cout << "Введите адрес абонента:";
        fflush(stdin);
        cin >> poisk_adress;
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; ((i < kol_el) && k != -1); i++)
        {
            if ((strcmp(poisk_sname, buf[i].sname)) == 0)
                if ((strcmp(poisk_adress, buf[i].adress)) == 0)
                {
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "Результаты запроса.\n";
                    cout << "Фамилия:" << buf[i].sname;
                    cout << "\nНомер телефона:" << buf[i].nomer;
                    cout << "\nАдрес:" << buf[i].adress;
                    k = -1;
                };
        }
        if (k == 0)
            cout << "\nКонтакт не найден.";
        cout << "\nПовторить запрос?[y/n]";
        fflush(stdin);
        otvet=getchar();
    } while (otvet != 'n');
    return 0;
}

int dobavit_kontakt()
{
    system("cls");
    contact buf;
    unsigned int n;
    char otvet = 'y';
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("telbook.dat", "ab");
    do
    {
        cout << "\nВведите фамилию:";
        fflush(stdin);
        cin >> buf.sname;
        cout << "\nВведите номер телефона";
        fflush(stdin);
        cin >> buf.nomer;
        cout << "\nВведите адрес абонента:";
        fflush(stdin); 
        cin >> buf.adress;
        fwrite(&buf, sizeof(contact), 1, f);
        cout << "\nКонтакт добавлен.\nХотите добавить ещё контакт?[y/n]";
        fflush(stdin);
        otvet = getchar();
    } while (otvet != 'n');
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}    

int udalit_kontakt()
{
    system("cls");
    char otvet = 'y';
    do{
        FILE *f;
        f = fopen("telbook.dat", "r+b");
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        int size = ftell(f);
        int kol_el = size / sizeof(contact);
        contact *buf = new contact[kol_el];
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fread(buf, sizeof(contact), kol_el, f);     
        fclose(f);
        f = fopen("telbook.dat", "w+b");
        char udalit_name[12];
        cout << "Введите номер контакта,который хотите удалить";
        fflush(stdin);
        cin >> udalit_name;
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; ((i < kol_el)&&k!=-1); i++)
        {
            if ((strcmp(udalit_name, buf[i].nomer)) == 0)
            {
                buf[i] = buf[kol_el-1];          
                fwrite(&buf, sizeof(contact), (kol_el-1), f);
                cout << "\nКонтакт успешно удалён!\n";
                k = -1;
            }
        }
        if (k == 0)
        {
            cout << "\nКонтакт не найден.\n";
            fwrite(&buf, sizeof(contact), kol_el, f);
        }
        cout << "Хотите удалить другой контакт?[y/n]";
        fflush(stdin);
        otvet = getchar();
        system("pause");
        fclose(f);
    } while (otvet != 'n');
    return 0;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    unsigned int rezh = 0;
    do{
        system("cls");
        const int NotUsed = system("color 03");
        cout << "Выберите действие:\n";
        cout << "1.Узнать адрес и фамилию по телефонному номеру.\n";
        cout << "2.Узнать номер телефона по фамилии и адреу.\n";
        cout << "3.Добавить новый контакт в базу данных.\n";
        cout << "4.Удалить контакт.\n";
        cout << "5.Показать всю базу контактов.\n";
        cout << "6.Выйти из программы.\n";
        cin >> rezh;
        switch (rezh)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            poisk_po_nomeru();
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            poisk_po_fam();
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            dobavit_kontakt();
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            udalit_kontakt();
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            vivod_bazi();
            break;
        }
    }
    } while (rezh != 6);
    system("cls");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Просто сделайте в структуре поле-признак удаления. Удаляется без копирования из хвоста в начало. Возможно реализовать восстановление. При обычном поиске пропускайте эти записи. Так во всех базах поступают. Для избавления от удалённых записей делается отдельная процедура упаковки. Или при добавлении новых записей занимать место удалённой

Comment: Нельзя плюсовать код с функциями в стиле "vivod_bazi()"

Comment: @Sergey, а чем плохо перемещение последнего элемента на место удаляемого, при этом оставляя остальные на своих местах? Всё равно автор делает полный перебор, то есть порядок записей неважен. Да и поле-признак удаления тогда не потребуется.

Comment: @Arhad быстрее и проще

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала встречный вопрос: почему бы для таких целей не воспользоваться файловыми базами данных? Например: sqlite.

Затем посмотрите этот ответ: [Работа со структурами данных в двоичном файле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464207/464215#464215), возможно наведёт на какие-то мысли.

Затем, чисто стиля ради: ну не используйте транслитерацию в коде. Дурная привычка. Лучше избавляться от неё как можно раньше.

Ну а теперь по сути. Я предлагаю вам отказаться тут от ручного управления памятью и воспользоваться `std::vector` и прочими прелестями STL (сначала код с комментариями, а потом моё предложение):

```
int udalit_kontakt()
{
    system("cls");
    char otvet = 'y';
    do{
        FILE *f;
        f = fopen("telbook.dat", "r+b");
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        int size = ftell(f);
        int kol_el = size / sizeof(contact);
        // старайтесь обходиться без ручного управления памятью. Дальше я покажу, что у вас это приводит к ошибке с утечкой памяти на каждой итерации цикла.
        //contact *buf = new contact[kol_el];
        std::vector<contact> contacts(kol_el);

        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        //fread(buf, sizeof(contact), kol_el, f);     
        fread(contacts.data(), sizeof(contact), contacts.size(), f);
        fclose(f);

        // Неплохо не растаскивать по коду аллокацию ресурса и его освобождение, поэтому
        // открытие перенесено ниже
        //f = fopen("telbook.dat", "w+b");
        // Используйте STL, вы же на C++ пишете, а если номер бангладеша или китая какой? там больше 12 цифр. А если пользователь просто больше введёт?
        //char udalit_name[12];
        std::string numberToErase;
        cout << "Введите номер контакта,который хотите удалить";
        fflush(stdin);
        cin >> numberToErase;
        //int k = 0;
        size_t i; // если мы ничего не засвопили, i после цикла будет равен contacts.size(), этот признак можно использовать.
        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (numberToErase == contacts[i].nomer)
            {
                // неплохое решение, вместо удаления сделать своп с последним элементом
                //buf[i] = buf[kol_el-1];      
                contacts[i] = contacts.back();
                // А вот тут косяк, в вашем первоначальном варианте buf и так указатель на область памяти, в которой хранятся последовательно
                // все элементы "базы", вы же передаёте адрес на адрес. Как рузультат всё перезаписывается мусором. В исходном коде
                // можно попытаться просто заменить [1] на [2]
                //fwrite(&buf, sizeof(contact), (kol_el-1), f); [1]
                //fwrite(buf, sizeof(contact), (kol_el-1), f); [2]
                // новая же запись вынесена за цикл

                //цикл тут достаточно завершить по break
                break;
            }
        }

        if (i == contacts.size())
        {
            cout << "\nКонтакт не найден.\n";
            // А вот этого можно не делать: вы же не изменили коллекцию, так зачем записывать то, что
            // и так не менялось? Плюс снова ошибка с записью адреса и мусора
            //fwrite(&buf, sizeof(contact), kol_el, f);
        }
        else
        {
            // а вот тут можно и удалить данные, для этого откроем файл, усечём его и запишем новыми данными
            f = fopen("telbook.dat", "wb");
            if (f) 
            {
                fwrite(contacts.data(), sizeof(contact), contacts.size() - 1, f);
                fclose(f);
                cout << "\nКонтакт успешно удалён!\n";
            }
            else
            {
                // ошибка: не смог открыть файл для записи
            }
        }
        cout << "Хотите удалить другой контакт?[y/n]";
        fflush(stdin);
        otvet = getchar();
        system("pause");

        // А вот в этом месте у вас ещё и утечка памяти была: вы не делали
        // delete[] buf;
        // в случае с std::vector он сам разрушится и память у вас не потечёт.
    } while (otvet != 'n');
    return 0;
}
```

Плюс вам незачем каждый раз считать размер файла: вы же знаете сколько структур удалили. А ещё можно сначала пробежаться и удалить все номера, а только потом, в один приход записать всё это в файл.

Т.е. я бы что-то вроде сделал (iostream не использую):

```
int udalit_kontakt()
{
    system("cls");
    char otvet = 'y';

    FILE *db = fopen("telbook.dat", "r+b");
    if (!db)
    {
        cerr << "Can't phone data base for reading\n";
        return -1;
    }

    fseek(db, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t size = ftell(db);
    size_t count = size / sizeof(contact);

    fseek(db, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // В этом месте у нас код не exception-safe:
    // если не хватит памяти, вылетит исключение и мы потеряем db, в результате утечёт дескриптор.
    std::vector<contact> contacts(count);
    fread(contacts.data(), sizeof(contact), contacts.size(), db);

    fclose(db);

    char ask = 'y';

    do {
        std::string numberToErase;
        cout << "Введите номер контакта,который хотите удалить";
        cin >> numberToErase;

        // не будем тут использовать std::remove_if и прелести C++11 :-)
        bool found = false;
        for (size_t idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx)
        {
            if (numberToErase == contacts[i].nomer)
            {
                contacts[idx] = contacts[count - 1];
                count--;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found)
            cout << "Контакт найден и подготовлен к удалению\n";
        else
            cout << "Контакт не найден";

        cout << "Хотите удалить другой контакт?[y/n]";
        cin >> ask;
    } while (ask == 'y' || ask == 'Y');

    // Явно что-то удалили
    if (count != contacts.size())
    {
        db = fopen("telbook.dat", "wb");
        if (!db) 
        {
            cerr << "Can't phone data base for writing\n";
            return -1;
        }

        // удалённые контакты постепенно всплывали в конец массива
        fwrite(contacts.data(), sizeof(contact), count, f);
        fclose(f);

        cout << "\nВыбранные контакты успешно удалёны!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Код не проверялся на компилябельность и показан только концепта ради.